# React - How to change styles when connected via a link to a browser page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hyperlink, styles

I decided to use Radio Buttons on my React project, installed the npm [kendo-react-inputs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-react-inputs) package, everything works well, but there is one caveat, there are some styles that I cannot change, for example, when I click on the radio button, a border with a red color appears, when using the package for the Radio button, I have included the style inside the **index.html** file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-default@latest/dist/all.css"></link>
```

If you follow this link, you will see that there are classes and styles that are applied to the classes there are some classes that I need to change the styles, I understand that I can download this file and then move it to my project, connect it and everything will be fine, but I think that it is personal burden for the project so I want to ask if there is a way to access these classes without downloading the whole file?